# Change the order of DataFrame columns using column names

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

I need to move the 3rd column to the end of the column list. This can be done as follows:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[0:2] + cols[4:] + cols[3]
df= df[cols]
```

However what if I don't know an index of the column that I'm interested in. Let's say that the only thing I know is that the column called `MyMagicCol` should be moved at the end of the column list.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it within a list, and you know the name of the column you're interested in, you could just do

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'MyMagicCol'] + ['MyMagicCol']
df = df[cols]
```

You could also do this with [`df.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and use the column names to slice your dataframe if you wanted to work with the columns directly.